# How to Reverse a 16 bit Hex Value in C?

Tags: c, hex, reverse, microchip

I'm trying to reverse my value of Pressure data and store this reversed result in the integer uint16_t Pcounts. I have found a macro that can be used and it seems to flip some bits but not others. Here is my code:

```
#define REV(X) ((X << 24) | (((X>>16)<<24)>>16) | (((X<<16)>>24)<<16) | (X>>24))

uint16_t PressureData;
uint16_t Pcounts;
Pcounts = REV(PressureData);
```

If PressureData = 0xAABB I would expect Pcounts to be 0xBBAA. However, the value comes out to be 0xBB00.

PressureData is the real-time value of pressure detected from a sensor.

Comment: Why are you shifting 16 and 24 bits? A 16-bit value don't have bits that high.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude good spot! The macro should've been:
 #define REV(X) ((X << 8) | (((X>>16)<<8)>>16) | (((X<<16)>>8)<<16) | (X>>8))

Comment: That macro is for reversing four 8-bit bytes in a 32-bit `unsigned` integer. It should not be expected to work with 16 bits or with signed integers. For 16-bits, you can use `#define Rev16(x) ((x) >> 8 | (x) << 8)`, assuming the argument is a 16-bit unsigned integer and the result is immediately assigned or cast to a 16-bit unsigned integer. (If it is not, then masking is needed.)

Comment: If your system is little-endian and you're storing in big-endian, you're doing a standard conversion - changing from a host-specific byte order to [network byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Networking).  This is usually done for portability.  It's so common, POSIX has functions defined to do it for you:  [`htons()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/htons.html) will convert a `uint16_t` from host to network byte order, and `ntohs()` will take network (big-endian) `uint16_t` and convert it to the current host byte order.

Answer (score 2):

> If PressureData = 0xAABB I would expect Pcounts to be 0xBBAA.

Let us assume with `abcd`, OP wants `cdab` (byte swap) and not `dcba` (nibble swap):

The below reverses bytes for a 32-bit value. [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60705649/how-to-reverse-a-16-bit-hex-value-in-c/60706558?noredirect=1#comment107404682_60705649)

```
#define REV(X) ((X << 24) | (((X>>16)<<24)>>16) | (((X<<16)>>24)<<16) | (X>>24))
```

To reverse bytes for a 16-bit *unsigned* value. [@Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60705649/how-to-reverse-a-16-bit-hex-value-in-c/60706558?noredirect=1#comment107405053_60705649) (Notice `()` about `X`.)

```
#define REV16_A(X) (((X) << 8) | ((X)>>8))
```

Better code would not rely on sign-ness, but force the issue.

```
#define REV16_B(X) (((uint16_t)(X) << 8) | ((uint16_t)(X)>>8))
```

Yet I see little reason for a macro here and simply use a helper function.  Make it `inline` if desired.

```
uint16_t rev16(uint16_t x) {
  return (x << 8) | (x >>8);
}
```

---

Further, I expect the desire to flip the bytes is an *endian* issue.  So if the code is ported, flipping the bytes might / might not be desired. In that case, it is likely the hardware is presenting the bytes in a certain endian which may/may not match the native endian of code.  Consider a helper function to handle that.

```
uint16_t endian_hw_to_native16(uint16_t x) {
  // endian sensitive code ...
}
```

Comment: For some reason, [BSD's `bswap16()` C code](https://github.com/diegocr/libnix/blob/master/stdlib/bswap16.c) does this:  `return ((x << 8) & 0xff00) | ((x >> 8) & 0x00ff);`

Comment: @AndrewHenle The only usefulness to the masks I see there is if `u_int16_t` is not `uint16_t`.

Comment: You see more than I did.  :-)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are overriding some bits.

Try using a function instead a macro:

```
swapped = ((input>>8)&0x0f) | // move byte 1 to byte 0
           (input<<8)&0xf0)); // byte 0 to byte 1
```